# Return List of entity instead of List of object

Tags: java, jpa

Eclipse / Java

I have a method to perform database query.

**myBean :**

```
List<Composicao> itemProdutoLista = compPrecoServico.buscar(Composicao.nomeQuery);
```

**The nomeQuery is :**

```
@NamedQuery(name = "nomeQuery", query= " SELECT composicao.valortotal,composicao.id FROM Composicao composicao
```

query - javax.persistence.query

```
public List<T> buscar(String nomeQuery) {
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(nomeQuery);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

My return List buscar get me that : **An Object elementData**

[image]

*How can I get an Entity Composicao elementdata in my return buscar method ?* instead of object elementData

Comment: @JB Nized thats it what I want regarding that last post about How to read Java ArrayList sub-items

Comment: I don't quite understand - `List<Composicao> itemProdutoLista` contains objects of type `Composicao` so which part of your code is incorrect?

Comment: see my printscreen. It gets me an Object elementData and I need an entity elementData

Comment: So when you iterate over `itemProdutoLista` you get `Object`? But your list is already correctly typed, so when the type would not match, you would get a `ClassCastException` most likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave you the query to use in your previous question:

```
SELECT composicao FROM Composicao composicao
```

Don't you understand that selecting two fields of an entity, as you're doing in the query

```
SELECT composicao.valortotal,composicao.id FROM Composicao composicao
                    ^-- first field      ^-- second field
```

doesn't return Composicao objects, but simply the two fields you selected: `valortotal` and `id`?

You're explicitely asking JPA to return **only** `valortotal` and `id`. Why would it return all the other fields and create a Composicao object? You want all the fields, and not just valortotal and id. So the query is (I'll repeat it a third time just in case):

```
SELECT composicao FROM Composicao composicao
```

Comment: we are back to that old question. I need to retrieve itemProdutoLista.get(0).get(0) for valorTotal and itemProdutoLista.get(0).get(1) for id. I know thats not exists get(x).get(y) but is what I need to @JB Nizet

Comment: `Composicao firstComposicao = itemProdutoLista.get(0); int valortotal = firstComposicao.getValortotal(); Long id = firstComposicao.getId();`. If you get back a `List<Composicao>`, every element of the list is a Composicao. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: I did it already but I got this : java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to br.com.getsprint.gestao360.entidade.Composicao @JB Nizet

Comment: You're talking about an exception caused by code you're not showing. And this exception is thrown because you're trying to cast a BigDecimal to ComposicaoPreco. BigDecimal is not a ComposicaoPreco, so that doesn't make any sense. That's like doing `Banana b = (Banana) truck;` A truck is not a banana. And casting it to Banana won't change anything to what a truck is: it's a truck and will always be a truck. So of course, you get a ClassCastException.

Comment: I got exception in this line you posted : Composicao firstComposicao = itemProdutoLista.get(0); theres no code to show. I pasted all my code in this post. and itemProdutoLista is printed in this post either

Comment: Then the query you're using is not the one I told you to use, three times already.

Comment: Im sorry but the query Im using is that one in this post and the code to execute the query is in this post either

Comment: *That one in this post*: which post? Your question or my answer? Edit your question and add the new query you're using, the code you're using to execute the query and get elements from the result, and the complete stack trace of the exception you get.

Comment: this post : @NamedQuery(name = "nomeQuery", query= " SELECT composicao.valortotal,composicao.id FROM Composicao composicao

Comment: For Christ sake, why do you ask questions if you don't read answers. The query you must use is `SELECT composicao FROM Composicao composicao`. Once again: the query you must use is `SELECT composicao FROM Composicao composicao`. I told you that once in the answer to your previous question, twice in the answer to this question, and now twice again in this comment. Will that be enough?

Comment: It worked the way I wanted... I apreciate your time and effort. Im sorry to bother you this way. I changed my query the way you told me and Composicao firstComposicao = itemProdutoLista.get(0);  I dont know how to thank you. you are a great person @JB Nizet. Greetings from Brazil

Comment: In the really Ive been avoiding to use the query select * because the entity has a lot of other related entities and it will be consuming a lot of server resources . thats my reason....

Comment: That's what lazy associations are for. Make your associations lazy (OnetoMany and ManyToMany associations are lazy by default). Anyway, you can make your query return only two fields, but then don't expect this query to return a List<Composicao>, as I already told you many times. Such a query will return a `List<Object[]>` where each Object[] contains two elements: valortotal and id. So, the signature of your buscar() method must be changed if you want to make it use such a query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about something like JPA.

Put a constructor on your entity (besides the empty/default constructor) that accepts every one of your query arguments.

```
@Entity
public class Jedi
   @Id private int id;
   private String name;

   //required by the standard
   public Jedi(){}

   public Jedi(int id, String name) {
     this.id = id;
     this.name = name;
   }

   //...
 }
```

Then your query

```
select NEW org.starwars.Jedi(j.id,j.name) from Jedi j where name.endsWith('Sky Walker')
```